# SQL Query using AS

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to create a query which deals with two tables:

Table: REGION

```
Column Name     Type      Constraint
REGION_Cd       Number    Primary Key
REGION_Desc     String
```

Table: STATS

```
Column Name     Type      Constraint
AGE             Number    Primary Key
REGION          Number    Foreign Key to REGION (REGION_Cd)
POPULATION      Number
```

How could I create a query such that it finds the population for two age groups (0-15, 16-30) and displayed in the following format:

```
Region_Desc    AgeGroup     Population
South          0‐15         11253
South          16‐30       235234
```

Since the AgeGroup column isnt actually a column in the tables, I should be using an AS statement, correct?

Comment: case when age between 0 and 15 then '0-15' else when age between 16 and 30 then '16-30' case else 'over 30'

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like... but it assumes you want sum of population in age group/region. which may or maynot be correct depending on how population works in the database

```
Select Region_Desc, case when age between 0 and 15 then '0-15' 
  when age between 16 and 30 then '16-30' 
  else 'over 30' end as AgeGroup, 
sum(Population) as Population
FROM Region INNER JOIN STATS on region_Cd = Region
GROUP BY Region_DESC, AgeGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Region_DESC, AgeGroup, Population
FROM
(select REGION, sum(POPULATION) as Population, '0-15' AS AgeGroup
from STATS
Where Age between 0 and 15
group by REGION
union
Select REGION, SUM(POPULATION) as Population, '16-30' As AgeGroup
from STATS
Where Age between 16 and 30
group by REGION) s
join REGION on REGION_CD = REGION
```

Comment: I think there's a FROM statement missing after the first 'Population', no? Could you maybe clarify?

Comment: Yep. sorry about that, was answering on my mobile phone!