# Something syntactically wrong with this SQL statement?

Tags: sql, syntax, sqlite

I keep getting an error when I try running this query in mysqlite3:

```
SELECT Region_DESC, AgeGroup, Population
(select REGION, sum(POPULATION) as Population, '0-15' AS AgeGroup
from STATS
Where Age between 0 and 15
group by REGION
union
Select REGION, SUM(POPULATION) as Population, '16-30' As AgeGroup
from STATUS
Where Age between 16 and 30
group by REGION) s
join REGION on REGION_CD = REGION
```

I'm getting the following error:
Error: near "SELECT": syntax error

Is there anything wrong with the query, syntax-wise?

Comment: Already fixed in the [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982255/sql-query-using-as#15982355).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `FROM` right after the word 'Population'.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong. You basically have:

```
SELECT something
(select somethingelse FROM somethingelsetable) s
join REGION on REGION_CD = REGION
```

I guess you are missing FROM before the parentheses...

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect Query ... missing From Clause in the first line.

Comment: @MarkLinus how is the answer different from other answers ? can you please explain